# How to dynamic add/remove control with Expression Blend?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, expression-blend

A while I go, I made a demo application with Expression Blend.

My first screen is a big selections of Buttons, so when user click on any of button, it goes to the MainView.

Then in the MainView, I have a list of Menu items that user can click and shows up its corresponing DisplayView. (Appointment Menu Item will shows up AppointmentView etc).

Everything is good, I can click the MenuItem, the Views shows up with animation and transition effects.

But the thing is, with creating in Expression Blend, the MainView, Menu, AppointmentView etc every thing is predefined in the XAML. So when user load the first screen has to load everything into memory.

Now thinking of it, shouldn't the MainView etc be dynamically add into the screen?
How do I do it with Expression Blend?  Or the only way to do is just....do it in code-behind myself (writting StoryBoard etc for the dynamic add/remove controls?)

If there is any example/tutorial of doing it, it will be great.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have very limited possibilities to conditionally load or unload controls exclusively in Blend without writing code-behind.

In general an opening tag in XAML is equivalent to a parameter-less constructor of some class object. As soon as you write the tags your are instantiating an object but that doesn't mean that it's visual appearance is loaded into memory. This only happens when the control is actually shown on the screen.

In my opinion the leanest way to control the appearance of some control is to use a single-child control. Take a Border control for example and add the user control you want to conditionally load to its child property, so you can decide for example whether to load or unload a control.

But unfortunately I think you have to do this in code as well. Take this easy code snippet:

```
// either instantiate in code or use from markuup
Border myBorder = new Border();

// the control you want to conditionally appear and disappear
UserControl myUserControl = new UserControl();
myBorder.Child.Add(myUserControl);
```

Of course a much more sophisticated approach is to use Grids. Here you have to use attached properties to add or remove child elements:

```
// either instantiate in code or use from markuup
Grid myGrid = new Grid();

// the control you want to conditionally appear and disappear
UserControl myUserControl = new UserControl();

// set the target position inside the Grid via the Grids attached properties
Grid.setRow(myUserControl, 1);
Grid.setColumn(myUserControl, 0);

// actually add the control
Grid.Children.Add(myUserControl);
```

Although I am pretty sure you were aware of all of that I am hoping it helped a bit :)